# I need help fixing MATLAB issues as it says not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, openpose

I am trying out a project https://github.com/janstenum/GaitAnalysis-PoseEstimation and when I run the command correctLegID_openpose.m as said in the documentation, I get this error

```
 Not enough input arguments.

Error in correctLegID_openpose (line 3)
file = sprintf('%s%s',output_name,'_openpose.mat');

Error in run (line 91)
evalin('caller', strcat(script, ';'));
```

I tried running the command normally by using

`run("correctLegID_openpose.m")`

Comment: `dbstop if error` is your friend.  You'll stop where the error happens, **in context**, so you can look at the variables referenced on the failing line.

Answer (score 1):

`run()` is for scripts, not for functions that take arguments.  If correctLegID_openpose.m is on your [Matlab search path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html), you can just call it directly and supply the missing input argument:

```
output_name = 'filename';
correctLegID_openpose(output_name)
```